# accelerometer iPhone not stable? (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, accelerometer, cmmotionmanager

I am using the accelerometer in landscape(iPhone 5s) for a game, but it looks like it is not 100% stable, or I am doing something wrong..

This is how I use it:

```
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
        // 2
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler:{
            data, error in

            var currentX = self.hond.position.x
            // 3
            var datay2 = Double()
            if data.acceleration.y < 0.02 {
                if data.acceleration.y < -0.35{
                    datay2 = -0.35
                }
                else{
                    datay2 = data.acceleration.y
                }
                self.destX = currentX - 0.09 * CGFloat(datay2 * 100)
            }

            else if data.acceleration.y > 0.02 {
                if data.acceleration.y > 0.35{
                    datay2 = 0.35
                }
                else{
                    datay2 = data.acceleration.y
                }
                self.destX = currentX - 0.09 * CGFloat(datay2 * 100)
            }

        })

    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        hond.position.x = destX
    }
```

Am I using it right? What can be the cause of the unexpected movements? Sometimes nothing happens when I tilt the device, sometimes the player("hond") moves when I am not tilting the device and tilting doesn't change anything..

Comment: You probably want to implement some kind of low-pass filter or something to smooth out the values. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter

Comment: "Additionally, you do not need to filter the acceleration data because device-motion separates gravity and user acceleration." , quoted from: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html

Comment: That doesn't mean that slight movements and unwanted 'judder' aren't reported. You still need to filter if you don't want the slightest of movements to cause changes in the readings.